# PDF not loading in PWA desktop app in Mac

Tags: c#, angular, macos, progressive-web-apps, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js in my angular app to load pdf from a .Net web api. The pdf is loading every where except the desktop PWA app in Mac. In the Mac PWA app, it's loading as blank screen. I installed the desktop PWA app from the Chrome browser's install button in Mac. There is no error in console. I am not being able to understand the cause of the issue. Please help.

Comment: There is actually no real need to use pdf.js since every modern browser (unless mobile) support the display of PDF files. Other than that, one can only guess what the issue here is. You have to do some debugging on your own.

Comment: Can anybody help me to fix the issue please? I am still struggling with it. Thanks.